# Confused about why a labels .Tag property, isn't doing what I think it should

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using C# in a WinForms application. I'm trying to set the value of a label based on the date of a file. The "File.GetLastWriteTime" method will return "12/31/1600" if it doesn't find the file. If it doesn't, I want the label to show "Not found". When stepping through the code below, the value for the lblSqlC.Tag match's "12/31/1600". yet the "If" statement finds it false.

```
lblSqlC.Tag = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\sql.exe").ToShortDateString();

if (lblSqlC.Tag == "12/31/1600")
{
   lblSqlC.Text = "Not Found";
}
else
{
   lblSqlC.Text = lblSqlC.Tag;
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're not using File.Exists to detect if the file exists?

Comment: Wny use the .Tag property? In you snippet you would simply use a local variable of type string (used for the comparison and the assignment).

Comment: I don't need to. I can use "File.GetLastWriteTime" to check for the files existence AND get the date if it exists.

Comment: But it becomes very less obvious what your code does, just for this micro-optimization, while using `File.Exists` makes it crystal clear that you're checking if the file exists or not.

Comment: After seeing your post below... I agree. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. The [Tag Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) is of type [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx), so your comparison tests if the object stored in the [Tag Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) is the same reference as `"12/31/1600"` which is not the case.
2. You're converting the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) value to a string, which results in a different string depending on the operating system's locale settings. So even if 1. worked, your code wouldn't work on all systems.

Use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) to check if the file exists or not:

```
if (!File.Exists(@"c:\sql.exe"))
{
   lblSqlC.Text = "Not Found";
}
else
{
   lblSqlC.Text = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\sql.exe").ToShortDateString();
}
```

If you really want to avoid using [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx), compare the value returned by [File.GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx) to a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) value, without converting to string:

```
DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\sql.exe");

// If the file does not exist, GetLastWriteTime returns 12:00 midnight,
// January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted
// to local time.
if (dt == new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
{
   lblSqlC.Text = "Not Found";
}
else
{
   lblSqlC.Text = dt.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: It's not so much that I was trying to avoid it, as much as type less code. But your answer does a good job explaining both routes I can take. I only recently "discovered" the Tag property. I assumed it was of type String since the .Text proprty was. I didn't realize it was of type Object. Thanks for the lesson, and the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 4):

You need to compare strings as strings if you're using the `==` operator.  So this block:

```
if (lblSqlC.Tag == "12/31/1600")
{
   lblSqlC.Text = "Not Found";
}
```

Should be changed to either:

```
if ((string)lblSqlC.Tag == "12/31/1600")
{
   lblSqlC.Text = "Not Found";
}
```

Or:

```
if (lblSqlC.Tag != null && lblSqlC.Tag.Equals("12/31/1600"))
{
   lblSqlC.Text = "Not Found";
}
```

Otherwise, as @dtb mentions, it simply uses the default `==` operator defined on `object` and tests that the references are equal (and they probably are not equal) as opposed to their values.

Comment: Comparing DateTime values as strings isn't really a good idea. ToShortDateString returns a localized string.

Comment: @JimDel, you convert it into a string, so the value stored in the `.Tag` property is actually a string.  However, operator overload resolution (like method resolution) works on the type known at *compile-time*.  And at compile time, because `.Tag` is a property of type `object`, all that is known about it is that it's an `object` and so it drops down and uses the version of `==` defined for `object` which results in a reference comparison instead of a string-value comparison.